# How do I revise the existing Index query to add cell value from other sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**How do I add Module # column to the existing Index query?**

The Index queries (Index!W2) and (Index!AJ2) are designed to
display the cumulative assessment scores from sheets: (Module 1 - Module 4). The query result displays the following:

Index!W2 (Cumulative list from Modules 1-4, values:'No' or '0' or '1')

- Standard
- Learner
- Grade

Index!AJ2 (Cumulative list from Modules 1-4, values: 'Yes' or '2)

- Standard
- Learner
- Grade

**The goal is to have the query result returned in sheets: Administrative View and Grade Level Dashboard**

[image: Example Admin View result]

The 'Module #' is located in sheets (Module 1 - 4), in cell 'A2'. Each Module sheet is a cumulative list of assessment results (grouped by Module). How do I add this column in the Index sheet queries?

See [Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Vp-hTQst8ucFXT4CwUJm66BrT9JH9bzo8alCHESv8Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Please do not expect that a user can/should/must open your spreadsheet to (better) understand your question. A description and explanation of the role and function of the formulas on "Index" W2 and AD2 should be included in the body of your question. Similarly the effect of the Module value should be explained and you should provide an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the description, and explanation for additional clarification, in addition to more clearly explaining the expected results.

Comment: Please don't use an image to describe data; data should be inckluded in your question. You can create a free online markdown table at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. I have noticed several questions about your spreadsheet and I feel that _in this case_ there is assumed knowledge. For example, the references to cumulative assessment scores, Modules, Index W2 and AJ2: these are all passing references that don't provide the user with any detailed understanding of the various sheets, data or formula; they don't explain what you are trying to do, and what, exactly, is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Added formula here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Vp-hTQst8ucFXT4CwUJm66BrT9JH9bzo8alCHESv8Y/edit#gid=951549940) for you to test out:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(A2:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,index(match(,0/(indirect(c&"!A:A")<>""))),
 rep_,indirect(c&"!A8"):index(indirect(c&"!A:A"),Σ), grp_,hstack(indirect(c&"!C8"):index(indirect(c&"!AF:AF"),Σ),indirect(c&"!AH8"):index(indirect(c&"!BK:BK"),Σ)), header_,hstack(indirect(c&"!C4:AF4"),indirect(c&"!AH4:BK4")), header_2,hstack(indirect(c&"!C5:AF5"),indirect(c&"!AH5:BK5")), module,indirect(c&"!A2"), size_,2,
 Λ,reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(wrapcols(index(header_,c),rows(rep_),index(header_,c)),rep_,choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c)),wrapcols(index(header_2,c),rows(rep_),index(header_2,c)),wrapcols(module,rows(rep_),module))))), 
 filter(Λ,regexmatch(index(Λ,,3)&"","No|1|0")+regexmatch(index(Λ,,4)&"","No|1|0"))))))
```

[image]